# NVD3.js Given X-Axis Value, Get all Lines' Y-Axis Values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using the line-with-focus chart ( View Finder ) example in nvd3. That means there's 3 or 4 lines ( series ) being drawn on the graph. When i hover over any of the lines I want to get back all the y-values for all lines of that given x-axis position ( for the most part these will be interpolated y-values per line ).

I see in the `nv.models.lineWithFocusChart` source code that using a callback for the `elementMouseover.tooltip` event I can get my data's x-value back for the data points on the line.

The closest part of the source code that does what i want is with the `interactiveGuideline` [code for the lineChart examples](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/lineChart.js#L246-L294). However, i don't want to create a `<rect>` overlay with `elementMousemove` interaction. I think i can modify this code to filter my data and get each line's y-value, but I'm sure there's an easier way I'm not seeing.

I think I'm on the right track, but just wondering if someone had this need before and found a quicker route than the rabbit hole I'm about jump in.

Thanks for feedback

Comment: You could pass the cursor's x position to `.invert()` of your x axis scale to get the "real" value at that position.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: thanks for the reply. I did not even know about `.invert()`. However, i really screwed this question up. I already have the x-value for a position. What i need is a every lines y-value for that given x. I've updated all parts of this question.

Comment: This is more difficult. If the position doesn't match a data point, you will have to compute the y values yourself based on the nearest data points and the line interpolation.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: correct. That's why the part of the `lineGraph` code ( link below ) that uses `nv.interactiveBisect` seems to be where i can steal some of that logic from https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/lineChart.js#L254-L265

Comment: That should certainly help, yes. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431595/how-do-i-return-y-coordinate-of-a-path-in-d3-js) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic functionality you're looking for, it still needs a bit of finesse and styling of the tooltips.  (Right now the tooltip blocks the view of the points...)

Key code to call *after* the drawing the chart in (for example, within the `nv.addGraph` function on the NVD3 live code site):

```
 d3.selectAll("g.nv-focus g.nv-point-paths")
    .on("mouseover.mine", function(dataset){

      //console.log("Data: ", dataset);

      var singlePoint, pointIndex, pointXLocation, allData = [];
      var lines = chart.lines;

      var xScale = chart.xAxis.scale();
      var yScale = chart.yAxis.scale();
      var mouseCoords = d3.mouse(this);
      var pointXValue = xScale.invert(mouseCoords[0]);

      dataset
          .filter(function(series, i) {
            series.seriesIndex = i;
            return !series.disabled;
          })
          .forEach(function(series,i) { 
              pointIndex = nv.interactiveBisect(series.values, pointXValue, lines.x());
              lines.highlightPoint(i, pointIndex, true);

              var point = series.values[pointIndex];

              if (typeof point === 'undefined') return;
              if (typeof singlePoint === 'undefined') singlePoint = point;
              if (typeof pointXLocation === 'undefined')
                pointXLocation = xScale(lines.x()(point,pointIndex));

              allData.push({
                  key: series.key,
                  value: lines.y()(point, pointIndex),
                  color: lines.color()(series,series.seriesIndex)
              });
          }); 


      /*
      Returns the index in the array "values" that is closest to searchVal.
      Only returns an index if searchVal is within some "threshold".
      Otherwise, returns null.
      */
      nv.nearestValueIndex = function (values, searchVal, threshold) {
            "use strict";
            var yDistMax = Infinity, indexToHighlight = null;
            values.forEach(function(d,i) {
               var delta = Math.abs(searchVal - d);
               if ( delta <= yDistMax && delta < threshold) {
                  yDistMax = delta;
                  indexToHighlight = i;
               }
            });
            return indexToHighlight;
      };

     //Determine which line the mouse is closest to.
     if (allData.length > 2) {
            var yValue = yScale.invert( mouseCoords[1] );
            var domainExtent = Math.abs(yScale.domain()[0] - yScale.domain()[1]);
            var threshold = 0.03 * domainExtent;
            var indexToHighlight = nv.nearestValueIndex(
              allData.map(function(d){ return d.value}), yValue, threshold
            );
            if (indexToHighlight !== null)
              allData[indexToHighlight].highlight = true;
                //set a flag you can use when styling the tooltip
      }


      //console.log("Points for all series", allData);

      var xValue = chart.xAxis.tickFormat()( lines.x()(singlePoint,pointIndex) );

      d3.select("div.nvtooltip:last-of-type")
        .html(
          "Point: " + xValue + "<br/>" +

          allData.map(function(point){
            return "<span style='color:" + point.color + 
              (point.highlight? ";font-weight:bold" : "") + "'>" + 
              point.key + ": " + 
              chart.yAxis.tickFormat()(point.value) +
              "</span>";
          }).join("<br/><hr/>")
        );

    }).on("mouseout.mine", function(d,i){ 
          //select all the visible circles and remove the hover class

      d3.selectAll("g.nv-focus circle.hover").classed("hover", false);
    });
```

The first thing to figure out was which objects should I bind the events to?  The logical choice was the Voronoi path elements, but even when I namespaced the event names to avoid conflict the internal event handlers nothing was triggering my event handling function.  It seems that a parent `<g>` event captures the mouse events before they can reach the individual `<path>` elements.  However, it works just fine if instead I bind the events to the `<g>` element that contains the Voronoi paths, and it has the added benefit of giving me direct access to the entire dataset as the data object passed to my function.   That means that even if the data is later updated, the function is still using the active data.

The rest of the code is based on the [Interactive Guideline code for the NVD3 line graphs](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/lineChart.js#L254-L265), but I had to make a couple important changes:

- Their code is inside the closure of the chart function and can access private variables, I can't.  Also the context+focus graph has slightly different names/functionality for accessing chart components, because it is made up of two charts.  Because of that:

  - `chart` in the internal code is `chart.lines` externally,
  - `xScale` and `yScale` have to be accessed from the chart axes,
  - the color scale and the x and y accessor functions are accessible within `lines`,
  - I have to select the tooltip instead of having it in a variable
- Their function is called with custom event as the `e` parameter that has already had the mouse coordinates calculated, I have to calculate them myself.
- One of their calculations uses a function (`nv.nearestValueIndex`) which is only initialized if you create an interactive layer, so I had to copy that function definition into mine.

I think that about covers it.  If there's anything else you can't follow, leave a comment.

Comment: you're awesome. this overlaps with the route i was going down. thanks for all the description!