# D3 Getting Y value of a trend line for current X

Tags: d3.js

I'm drawing a line chart from database values of the current day, I'm also drawing a second "trend line" after some calculations to well... know how they day is going, this trend line has only 4 points for 6 a.m., 8 a.m., 12m. and 6 p.m. For example:

```
[Data]
06:00:00, 10
08:00:00, 30
12:00:00, 110
06:00:00, 320
```

I would like to check if my current value is below or above my trend line to display warnings or maybe send notifications (at any given time during the day, preferably the latest time read). I've tried several things but all I can get are the known 4 values(for those hours) of my trend line, nothing in between.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431595/how-do-i-return-y-coordinate-of-a-path-in-d3-js

Comment: I tried GetpointAtLength but since my trend line has only 4 points, it goes from Y(1) to Y(2) etc

Comment: This gets the coordinates of the drawn line, independent of how many underlying data points there are.